# Histogram of the words in the Spanish Dictionary

Tags: histograms, dictionary

I am trying to do the exact same histogram as below, but in Spanish.

```
Histogram[{StringLength /@ DictionaryLookup[], dataPnJ}, {1}, "Probability"]
```

Comment: An extended example is available under `Applications` on the doc page for [Histogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined what `dataPnJ` is, but this should get you started:

```
Histogram[StringLength /@ DictionaryLookup[{"Spanish", "*"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: i am trying to represent them as the frequency of their probability, your suggestion does  do the spanish dictionary but shows frequencies. i am trying
`Histogram[
 StringLength /@ 
  DictionaryLookup[{"Spanish", *}, {1}, "Probability"]]` but it does not work

Comment: Your brackets are wrong and the `*` is actually a regex `"*"` (note the quotes). This works `Histogram[
 StringLength /@ 
  DictionaryLookup[{"Spanish", "*"}], {1}, "Probability"]`

Comment: no luck, it shows a blank graph.

Comment: This is the output of Mathematica 12.0: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1Be.png